# Why Python import is looking package from another environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio, import, environment, streamlit

I am using different environment (Conda) for the project (python 3.10.9). When I import libraries and packages etc, it is importing from that environment's path. But when I import streamlit-extras package, even though it is installed on the same environment, It is searching from other version (python 3.7) and therefore giving ModuleNotFound Error. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-the-full-path) and other questions but couldn't solve my problem. I checked the current environment's location and streamlit-extras is there.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit_extras.let_it_rain'
Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/Users/abduraimovusmanjon/Desktop/danger/pages/1__Insights.py", line 16, in <module>
    from streamlit_extras.let_it_rain import rain
```

As seen from the error, it is looking some other path (python 3.7) for only this package, even if the package is located on the same environment which I am working. Any other import is working without problem.
[image]

Is there easier way that whenever I import, python will stick on the current environment?
Or any other way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have another installed version of `streamlit-extras`, which was installed outside of the `pip` package manager.

And that other version takes precedence over the `pip` one.

You can check your `PATH` variable: it will show you which directories are looked at to resolve your `streamlit-extras` and the order in which they are checked.

One of the earlier paths likely points to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib`. Either remove it, or re-order paths so that your Conda environment path shows first.

Comment: Aha got it. Thank you, I will remove and check.